# Android: Write Adapter for ListView in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Im programming a app which shows meals with a picture,name and a short description. If pressed on one meal it should extend the size of the listitem to
get from this http://puu.sh/lmwKn/b5f6f1d54a.jpg to this http://puu.sh/lmwJo/943f7349d3.jpg.

Now to add meals to the ListView i wrote an MealAdapter, i dont know how to get the view of the list of the comments

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.gericht_list_layout, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gericht_image);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gericht_title);
        viewHolder.descTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gericht_sub_title);
        viewHolder.comments = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gericht_comments);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.name.setText(data.get(position).name);
    viewHolder.descTxt.setText(data.get(position).subName);

    int id = convertView.getResources().getIdentifier(
            data.get(position).img, "drawable",
            context.getPackageName());
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource(id);

    return convertView;
}
```

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gericht_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/no_image"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gericht_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gericht_image"
    android:text="Kein Name"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gericht_sub_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:text="Keine genauere Beschreibung"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gericht_image"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/gericht_comments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So i want to draw the gericht_comments listview but i dont know how

Comment: is `ExpandableListView` what you want?

Comment: First of all, thank you. But now i have another question. How can i make the "expansion" effect of  the ExpandableListView smooth ?

Comment: Sorry, not really sure about that one - never used it myself. You could try searching for some library that handles animations on top of ExpandableListView.